# Affect the properties and animations of another division by clicking on some other division

Tags: html, css

I have following 2 divisions:
`<div class="left"></div>`
`<div class="left"></div>`

```css
div.left
{
  background:orange;
  position: absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:300px;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
  z-index:1;
  transition: 1s;
}
div.right
{
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:300px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div.left:focus
{
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left" tabindex="0">left page</div>
<div class="right">right page</div>
```

now i wish to change the width and padding of right page when I click on the left page.
Also I need a flip animation in the left page with the use of CSS (*as simple as possible because i am new to this*) to make it look like a book.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ajy1sz64/ I doubt you can make the desired flip animation with CSS. It will probably even be pretty hard if you are using javascript to make the animation. Have you seen an online examples that achieves this?

Comment: Thank you. This really helped.
yes, i have checked some online examples of flipping but i am not able to understand the concept.
I am using transform: rotate() but it won't solve the purpose.

Comment: This website looks interesting in your case: https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/introduction.html It explains the 3D transforms. Looks like I have some reading to do as well :p.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ajy1sz64/2/ This is how far I managed to get on this.